# AWS Elastic Beanstalk- SecurityGroup Error Message

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been dealing with this for a few days already:

> Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Degraded. Auto
> Scaling activity failed 16 seconds ago with error: The parameter
> SecurityGroup is not recognized. Launching EC2 instance failed. At
> 2023-11-30T06:50:17Z an instance was started in response to a
> difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the
> capacity from 0 to 1. Initialization in progress (running for 4
> minutes). There are no instances. Auto Scaling group desired capacity
> is set to 1.

To resolve the errors, I tried checking under EC2 alongside Elastic Beanstalk configurations to see if the appropriate Security Group was included. It was.

However, this error message still continues to pop up for me, and now it seems like I'm out of options apart from contacting AWS directly. Wanted to check if I missed out anything in the error message above?